# Passing command line arguments to plink with -m option

Tags: plink

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to *plink* used with -m option to execute commands from a file as follows:

```
plink -pw password user@<ip> -m script.sh arg1
```

script.sh is:

```
#!bin/bash
echo $1
```

When I run the plink command above on a Windows machine, the argument is ignored and nothing is printed. Is there any way to make it work?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

After looking at plink source code, it seems the answer is no. The content of the script file is read into a variable as if it was typed without on command line without -m option.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late, but still.
I compose temp file on-the-fly and run plink with it. Example with passing password to sudo su:

```
@echo off
rem The file with usefull shell commands 
set shfile=sh_to_run_under_root.sh
set /p pwd="Enter password: "

rem Recreate temp bash file
if exist temp.sh del /q /f temp.sh
>>temp.sh echo echo "%pwd%" ^| sudo -S su
type %shfile% >> temp.sh

plink -t -m "temp.sh" -pw %pwd% user@1.2.3.4    

rem Delete temp file
del /q /f temp.sh
```